# JSON serialization: Use a parameter value as a name for object

Tags: c#, json

I have model that I need to serialize to JSON

```
public class MetadataContextViewModel : IHaveCustomMapping
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }


        public void CreateMappings(Profile configuration)
        {
            configuration.CreateMap<Domain.Entities.MetadataContext, MetadataContextViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Parameter.Name))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Type,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Parameter.Type))
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.Id,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Parameter.Id1));
        }

    }
```

And implementation code:

```
List<MetadataContextViewModel> metadataContextList = _context.MetadataContexts
                .ProjectTo<MetadataContextViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();


        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true,
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        };
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(metadataContextList, options);
```

My `jsonString` has value:

```
 [
  {
    "name": "description",
    "id": "http://description"
  },
  {
    "name": "title",
    "id": "http://title"
  },
  {
    "name": "accessURL",
    "id": "http://accessURL",
    "type": "@id"
  }
]
```

Can I make some custom JSON serialization so that `"name"` value become name of it's object, for example:

```
   [
     "description": {
        "id": "http://description"
      },
    "title":  {
        "id": "http://title"
      },
     "accessURL": {
        "id": "http://accessURL",
        "type": "@id"
      }
    ]
```

I guess I can make a new `IdTypeModel` and `Dictionary<string,IdTypeModel>`   where `IdTypeModel` would have

```
public class IdTypeModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

but this does not seems as a right solution to me.

Comment: You really have a `Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but I reckon that woudn't serialise properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a custom converter for your class along the lines of

```
public class MyClassConverter : JsonConverter<MyClass>
```

(Substitute `MetadataContextViewModel` for `MyClass`).

Assuming a class definition like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Getting it *into* a JSON string is pretty easy, we just need to ensure that we are respecting your `JsonSerializerOptions`:

```
public class MyClassConverter : JsonConverter<MyClass>
{
    public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyClass instance, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instance.Name?.Trim()))
            throw new JsonException("Expected non-null, non-empty Name");
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        var formattedName = JsonSerializer.Serialize(instance.Name, options);
        var deserializedName = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(formattedName, options);
        writer.WritePropertyName(deserializedName);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new{instance.Id, instance.Type}, options);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    // ...
}
```

For a test like this:

```
var instances = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass
    {
        Name = "description",
        Id = "http://description"
    },
    new MyClass
    {
        Name = "title",
        Id = "http://title"
    },
    new MyClass
    {
        Name = "accessURL",
        Id = "http://accessURL",
        Type = "@id"
    }
};
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    Converters = {new MyClassConverter()}
};
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(instances, options);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

We will produce a JSON string like so:

```
[
  {
    "description": {
      "id": "http://description"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": {
      "id": "http://title"
    }
  },
  {
    "accessURL": {
      "id": "http://accessURL",
      "type": "@id"
    }
  }
]
```

---

The hard part is deserialization.

The gist of the approach is to check the current `JsonTokenType` of your `reader` and parse appropriately, for example:

```
public override MyClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    // Read opening '{'
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        throw new JsonException("Expected start object");
    reader.Read();

    // read the Name property
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
        throw new JsonException("Expected to read Name");

    string name = reader.GetString();
    var toReturn = new MyClass{Name = name};
    
   // read other properties that may or may not be present
   // ...
   return toReturn;
}
```

Of course you can make it arbitrarily resilient, like handling comments, checking for duplicates, handling unexpected values etc. (are empty strings valid, for example). A state machine is the appropriate way to handle these things, but for now a simple loop for reading class members will suffice:

```
public override MyClass Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    // Read opening '{'
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        throw new JsonException("Expected start object");
    reader.Read();

    // read the Name property
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
        throw new JsonException("Expected to read Name");

    string name = reader.GetString();
    var toReturn = new MyClass { Name = name };
    reader.Read();

    // Read opening '{' for class members
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        throw new JsonException("Expected start object for class members");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            reader.Read(); // consume closing ')' for class members
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                throw new JsonException("Expected end object for class");
            // do not consume the closing '}' for class
            break;
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            throw new JsonException("Expected to read next property name");

        var nextPropertyName = reader.GetString().Trim().ToLower();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.String)
            throw new JsonException("Expected to read next property value");
        var nextPropertyValue = reader.GetString();
        if (nextPropertyName == nameof(MyClass.Id).ToLower())
            toReturn.Id = nextPropertyValue.Trim();
        else if (nextPropertyName == nameof(MyClass.Type).ToLower())
            toReturn.Type = nextPropertyValue.Trim();
        else
            throw new JsonException("Unrecognized key:value {nextPropertyName}:{nextPropertyValue}");
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

---

You'll want to test that you can round-trip. That is, that you can serialize an instance and deserialize it back into the same representation as before (note: round-tripping can get weird when serializing floating point values depending on the serialization technique used).

```
string json1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(instances, options);
Console.WriteLine(json1);
var deserializedInstances = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(json1, options);
string json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(deserializedInstances, options);
Console.WriteLine(json2);
Console.WriteLine((json1 == json2 ? "Success" : "Failed to round-trip"))
```

Comment: This is what I need. Just one more thing, when I use annotation  `[JsonPropertyName("@id")]` in `MyClass()` it doesn't work with this convertor. How to fix that?

Comment: @Lube: You have a few choices. You can just manually use `@id` in your converter to write/read the name, or you can write a more generic converter that uses reflection to find the `JsonPropertyName` attribute and use that to get the name. The latter would basically be copying what System.Text.JSON does in a private method [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d783badaa38596beedefd58b59e2f031ba37c410/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Metadata/JsonPropertyInfo.cs#L344)